# Archive old Database Entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, archive

Workszenario:

I have a database filled with huge amounts of data every day. For **performance** i want to split off old data and new data. The new datas date is newer than one month.

My first thought was to split old data into one big database and the new one into another. But this is a critical way of seperating data on a live system, also because there are no ressources for such heavy database I/O.

So my question is if there are other possibilities to speed up the operating database by seperating new data from old one, but keep the old one accessible everytime ?

I've read something about partitioning but dont know if that will help in this case.

Comment: Usually you would keep all data in one table, but partition the table by date. So you only select from sectors with current data, whereas sectors with old dates will rarely be touched. This gives you the desired speed without having to think of copy mechanisms etc. I don't know much about how to partition a table by date, however, so I just give you this as a comment. Others can write an answer in more detail.

Comment: Databases are built to handle "huge amounts of data". You are suggesting a solution "split off old data" but don't say what performance problem you have? Do you want an answer that help you with your solution or your problem (which might or might not be the same)

Comment: I cant change the way the database is treated, so i want a suggestion or an answer to my possible solution.

Comment: @DanielKüppers: You didn't answer the question "What performance problem do you have?" But partitioning is probably your next step.

Comment: Do you have several disks to put the partitions on? Otherwise you will not gain anything. Same thing if your performance problem is caused by table scans.

Comment: No, i dont have multiple disks. Then i propably need to create a new database and port the old data into it to increase the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Partition table for your idea. I suggest that create different filegroup for your archive data in partitioning and then compress archive filegroup by following method. and set archive filegroup as readonly in order to disable any change data on it.

- In order to compress data specific partitions use following steps.

1- Right click on your table

2- Select Manage Compression

[image]

- In order to set readonly option for your filegrou use following steps.

1- Right click on your database

2- select FileGroup tabs

3- Enable readonly option.